# c# send discord webhook

Tags: c#, discord

Does anyone know how i would send all the data from the user to a discord webhook message?

So my code is like so:

```
        private void materialSingleLineTextField1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            userName = materialSingleLineTextField1.Text;
            rapcount(userName);
            materialLabel2.Text = "Username: " + materialSingleLineTextField1.Text;

            var client = new WebClient();

            var text = client.DownloadString("https://api.roblox.com/users/get-by-username?username=" + materialSingleLineTextField1.Text);

            Post post = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Post>(text);

            Id = post.Id;

            materialLabel3.Text = "ID: " + post.Id;
            materialLabel4.Text = "Online: " + post.IsOnline;

            var request = WebRequest.Create("https://www.roblox.com/headshot-thumbnail/image?userId=" + Id + "&width=420&height=420&format=png");

            using (var response = request.GetResponse())
            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = Bitmap.FromStream(stream);
            }

            //https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/450790622446485525/HW8nYfZ39J0VPKDcxEuLoYpwVbBt8qxF4uM1SMJGp8WXIlZ33jlqzSvMThM7rSoxJUJU

            materialSingleLineTextField1.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

and I want the username and ID sent as a message. Please help <3

Answer (score 1):

Uhm i just got this from someone else
class
[Link](https://pastebin.com/W6mMjNDz)
code

```
using (dWebHook dcWeb = new dWebHook())
{
     dcWeb.ProfilePicture = "https://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/original/4/42381/1196379-gas_mask_respirator.jpg";
     dcWeb.UserName = "Bot";
     dcWeb.WebHook = webHook;
     dcWeb.SendMessage("Hello");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is getting pretty old and dated but being the first result on Google as of right now, I felt posting my version and my preferred way of doing this, considering it took me a while to figure out.

Make sure to add a reference to System.Net.

```cs
using System.Net;
```

Method for keeping same webhook:

```cs
static void SendMs(string message)
{
    string webhook = "WEBHOOK_HERE";

    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    string payload = "{\"content\": \"" + message + "\"}";
    client.UploadData(webhook, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload));
}
```

Using this method:

```cs
SendMs("Hello, world!");
```

Method for changing webhook on call:

```cs
static void SendMs(string message, string webhook)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    string payload = "{\"content\": \"" + message + "\"}";
    client.UploadData(whurl, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload));
}
```

Using this method:

```cs
SendMs("Hello, world!", "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/...");
```

Hope this helps somebody out!